# Square barplot in seaborn

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, seaborn

I am trying to have a square & equally scaled bar plot in seaborn but no success so far. I would appreciate any help. Here is the code example:

```
time = [12, 21, 12, 31, 5, 4, 26]
run = ['A', 'B', 'c', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G']
ax = sns.barplot(run, time)
ax.set_ylabel("Seconds", fontsize=10)
plt.xticks(rotation=90)
ax.set(yticks=[0, 10, 20, 30, 40])
ax.axis('square')
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

[image]

Thanks a lot !

Comment: What is the problem? Your bar plot is pretty squared and equally scaled.

Comment: well the x axis is not equally spaced, the bars concentrated in left side.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just remove

```
ax.axis('square')
```

and this should be good to go.

```
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(10, 8))
time = [12, 21, 12, 31, 5, 4, 26]
run = ['A', 'B', 'c', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G']
ax = sns.barplot(x =run, y= time)
ax.set_ylabel("Seconds", fontsize=10)
plt.xticks(rotation=90)
ax.set(yticks=[0, 10, 20, 30, 40])
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

Comment: thanks for the response. Yes, I tried it already, it will scaled the x axis equally but the plot would not be square anymore.

Comment: `fig = plt.figure(figsize=(10, 8))` before the plot. You have to choose the right size, both no equal doesn't necessarily means square but I think you can come up with a number